# What is the best method to minimize code complexity when saving stack data to exploit parallelism?

Tags: design-patterns, parallel-processing, cuda, code-readability

I am attempting to accelerate some code with CUDA, and am under the constraints of preserving code readability/maintainability as much as possible.

I have found and parallelized a function buried within several functions/loops.  This function accounts for ~98% of processing time, but doesn't exploit enough parallelism alone to be useful (on the order of a couple blocks..). When executed simultaneously the code is much faster. However, as a result I am forced to maintain a big list of stack objects that I must iterate over several times, see the code below:

```
void do_work(int i, ...) {
    // computationally expensive stuff...
}

void prereq_stuff(int i) {
    int foo;
    double bar;

    // lots of big divergent control structures...

    do_work(i); // maybe arrive here..

    // output and what not that needs foo/bar...
}

int main() {

    for (int i = 0; i < BIG_NUMBER; i++) {
        prereq_stuff(i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Has turned into...

```
// a struct that contains all the stack data..
struct StackMem {
    int foo;
    double bar;
};

void do_work_on_gpu(List<StackMem> contexts) {
    // launch a kernel to handle to expensive stuff..
}

void prereq_stuff(StackMem* context, int i) {
    // maybe queue up data for do_work_on_gpu()...
}

void cleanup_stuff(StackMem* context, int i) {
    // output and what not that needs foo/bar...
}

int main() {

   List<StackMem> contexts; // some container of stack objects

   for (int i = 0; i < BIG_NUMBER; i++) {
        StackMem* context = contexts.add();
        prereq_stuff(context, i);
    }

    do_work_on_gpu(contexts); // calls the CUDA kernel

    for (int i = 0; i < contexts.size(); i++) {
        cleanup_stuff(contexts.get(i), i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is there some sort of design construct/pattern I can utilize here? Or is this as simple as it can get with having all the data to call do_work() available simultaneously?

Comment: It depends on the code/algorithm behind "lots of big divergent control structures". You wrote that the CPU version needed about 98% processing time. What's the ratio of the (partially) GPU version? And how long does `prereq_stuff` run in comparison to `do_work on_gpu`? I am not sure if there is a good general answer and this question might better be asked on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Shadow Obligatory reference to the [Code Review help centre](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to avoid wrongfully posted questions.

Comment: @Mast: I don't think that's actual code, it's more like a "sketch" of the code.

Comment: @einpoklum Exactly.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I would approach this scenario:

- Your context data structure will be either

  ```
  struct { int* foos; double* bars; } contexts;
  ```

  or

  ```
  struct context_t { int foos; double bar; };
  struct context_t* contexts;
  ```

  (or something equivalent but fancier, like maybe use a `gsl::span_t<context_t>`  if you know what that is)
- You will pre-allocate memory for all of your contexts, preferably pinned memory with `cudaMallocHost()` (that's why I didn't suggest `std::vector`).
- Instead of creating a context on each call to `prereq_stuff()`, just pass it    an iterator of to the specific context, or an index and the contexts array, so that it doesn't put its context in some arbitrary place in memory.
- Pass the array(s) of context using a single `cudaMemcpy()`.
- Each thread, or block, or whatever uses their id to decide which context to work on.
- Be careful about coalescing your reads, since the context is 12 bytes while memory reads on an NVIDIA GPU are in units of 32-byte (through the texture cache/`__ldg()`) or 128-byte.

PS - Whatever you end up implementing, make sure and [profile](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/gilesm/cuda/lecs/NV_Profiling_lowres.pdf) your code, and look at both the Compute and I/O times - and at the time you spend doing CPU, to see what potential you have for improvement.